# How to compile xsd files using ANT Tool

Tags: xsd

I have list of xsd's files to generate  as java object but i tried with maven build tool it is working fine. I used plugins in pom.xml.I tried with ANT build Tool it is not working.I tried with below links from google but its not working.https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/xjcTask.html .
In my project we are using ANT tool.So please any one help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To compile xsd files, you have to first create schemas (.java files). To do that you need to add taskdef, which is contained in this link you gave. Then you have to use ant xjc task. Here is an example:

```
<xjc schema="your.xsd.file" target="place.to.put.java.file" package="package.for.the.file.eg.com.soft.anonymous"/>
```

Now you have your .java files, bgm.ser and jaxb.properties created from xsd schemas, placed in target directory. To compile them just use ant javac task.
I hope this helped you. If not, please specify what exactly is the problem while you are trying to compile.

## 1

You can place taskdef in many places, but the best place will be just before your xjc task. So, for example, you have a target named xjc.target. In this target you put taskdef, and after that put xjc task and then javac.

Let me explain a little:

- Be sure that in you taskdef you have set properly fileset dir. It have to be directory where you put jaxb.jar file. Eg project/lib.
- After taskdef you use xjc task. In src give a path to your xsd file. In target write a path where you want to place java files. Eg src/java/files. In package you place package for your classes. For example if you put pl.com.website, you classes will go to src/java/pl/com/website.
- Now, you have your java files. To use them, you have to compile them using javac task. So you put in src path to those java files. In target you put path where you want to compile them (create .class files). And thats all.

Please try it step by step and if you have a problems please copy-paste console output for me. It would help me understand you problem better.

```
<target name="xjc.target">
    <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="path/to/jaxb/lib" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <xjc schema="your.xsd.file" target="${java.files.dir}" package="package.for.the.file.eg.com.soft.anonymous"/>

    <javac src="${java.files.dir}" target="${classes}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for you support .According to that link i placed taskdef in build.xml.I got erors in my project for some of package level code bcoz java object is not found.I coded for everythg using maven so now trying to convert to ANT project structure.Next step where i have to place ant xjc task.Then how to compile only xsd to generate java objects.

Comment: You can place taskdef in many places, but the best place will be just before your xjc task. So, for example, you have a target named xjc.target. In this target you put taskdef, and after that put xjc task and then javac. (check my answer edit #1)

Comment: <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
   <classpath>
     <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
   </classpath>
 </taskdef>
 <mkdir dir="xsd" />
 <xjc target="src" removeOldOutput="yes" package="com.ecoenergy.xml">
   <schema dir="schema" includes="*.xsd" />
   <depends dir="schema" includes="*.dtd" />
   <produces dir="build/generated-src/com/ecoenergy/xml" includes="**/*" />
 </xjc> i have used like this in build.xml file.when i tried to compile in cmd prompt using ANTits throwing error with below line <xjc target="src" removeOldOutput="yes" package="com.ecoenergy.xml">

Comment: Ok, but what does this error say? Can you copy it and paste here?

Comment: Hi goodmrng!!! It says Build failed due to src is not a valid version number .Perhaps you meant @destdir while building my app through ant

Comment: <target name="schema-to-java">
 <xjc destdir="./src/gen">
 <schema dir="./META-INF/xsd" includes="**/*.xsd"/>
 </xjc>
  </target> this also i tried when i to compile the project with ant command in cmd its saying build failed with all java objects not generated.I doubt whether we have to run javac task should run before that.that also i tried with javac cmd i gave in cmd prompt..